# How to create an efficient data structure for two-dimensional LINQ operations?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

Problem: I have 2 kinds of objects, lets call them `Building` and `Improvement`. There are roughly 30 `Improvement` instances, while there can be 1-1000 `Building`s. For each combination of `Building` and `Improvement`, I have to perform some heavy calculation, and store the result in a `Result` object.

Both `Building`s and `Improvement`s can be represented by an integer ID.

I then need to be able to:

- <strike>Access the `Result` for a given `Building` and `Improvement` efficiently</strike> (EDIT: see comment further down)
- Perform aggregations on the `Result`s for all `Improvement`s for a given `Building`, like .Sum() and .Average()
- Perform the same aggregations on the `Result`s for all `Building`s for a given `Improvement`

This will happen on a web-server back-end, so memory may be a concern, but speed is most important.

Thoughts so far:

1. Use a `Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, Result>` with `<BuildingID, ImprovementID>` as key. This should give me speedy inserts and single lookups, but I am concerned about `.Where()` and `.Sum()` performance.
2. Use a two-dimensional array, with one dimension for `BuildingID`s and one for `ImprovementID`s, and the `Result` as value. In addition, build two `Dictionary<int, int>` that map `BuildingID`s and `ImprovementID`s to their respective array row/column indexes. This could potentially mean max 1000+ `Dictionary`s, will this be a problem?
3. Use a `List<Tuple<int, int, Result>>`. I think this may be the least efficient, with O(n) inserts, though I could be wrong.

Am I missing an obvious better option here?

EDIT: Turns out it is only the aggregated values (per `Building` and per `Improvement`) I am interested in; see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, the test code was really informative :)

The solution for me turned out to be to forgo LINQ, and perform aggregation manually directly after the heavy calculation, as I had to iterate over each combination of Building and Improvement anyway.

Also, I had to use the objects themselves as keys, in order to perform calculations before the objects were persisted to Entity Framework (i.e. their IDs were all 0).

Code:

```cs
public class Building {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Improvement {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Result {
    public decimal Foo { get; set; }
    public long Bar { get; set; }
    ...

    public void Add(Result result) {
        Foo += result.Foo;
        Bar += result.Bar;
        ...
    }   
}

public class Calculator {
    public Dictionary<Building, Result> ResultsByBuilding;
    public Dictionary<Improvement, Result> ResultsByImprovement;

    public void CalculateAndAggregate(IEnumerable<Building> buildings, IEnumerable<Improvement> improvements) {
        ResultsByBuilding = new Dictionary<Building, Result>();
        ResultsByImprovement = new Dictionary<Improvement, Result>();
        for (building in buildings) {
            for (improvement in improvements) {
                Result result = DoHeavyCalculation(building, improvement);

                if (ResultsByBuilding.ContainsKey(building)) {
                    ResultsByBuilding[building].Add(result);
                } else {
                    ResultsByBuilding[building] = result;
                }

                if (ResultsByImprovement.ContainsKey(improvement)) {
                    ResultsByImprovement[improvement].Add(result);
                } else {
                    ResultsByImprovement[improvement] = result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void Main() {
    var calculator = new Calculator();
    IList<Building> buildings = GetBuildingsFromRepository();
    IList<Improvement> improvements = GetImprovementsFromRepository();
    calculator.CalculateAndAggregate(buildings, improvements);
    DoStuffWithResults(calculator);
}
```

I did it this way because I knew exactly which aggregations I wanted; if I required a more dynamic approach I would probably have gone with something like @MatthewWatson's Dictionary of Dictionaries.

Comment: Feel kinda bad accepting my own answer here, as both other answers were quite helpful, but in the end I had to solve the problem another way. Hopefully their answers can helpe someone else in a similar situation :)

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the Dictionary is most lookup efficent. The both lookup efficency and manipulation efficency is constant O(1), when accessed via key. This will help for access, the first point.

In the second and third you need to walk through all of the items O(n), so there is no way to speed it except you want to walk them through in specified order O(n*n) - then you can use SortedDictionray O(n), but you compromise the lookup and manipulation efficency (O(log n)).

So I would go with the 1st solution you post.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a "dictionary of dictionaries" to hold the Result data, for example:

```
//             Building ID ↓               ↓ Improvement ID
var data = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Result>>();
```

This would let you quickly find the improvements for a particular building.

However, finding the buildings that contain a particular improvement would require iterating over all the buildings. Here's some sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    sealed class Result
    {
        public double Data;
    }

    sealed class Building
    {
        public int Id;
        public int Value;
    }

    sealed class Improvement
    {
        public int Id;
        public int Value;
    }

    class Program
    {
        void run()
        {
            //             Building ID ↓               ↓ Improvement ID
            var data = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Result>>();

            for (int buildingKey = 1000; buildingKey < 2000; ++buildingKey)
            {
                var improvements = new Dictionary<int, Result>();

                for (int improvementKey = 5000; improvementKey < 5030; ++improvementKey)
                    improvements.Add(improvementKey, new Result{ Data = buildingKey + improvementKey/1000.0 });

                data.Add(buildingKey, improvements);
            }

            // Aggregate data for all improvements for building with ID == 1500:

            int buildingId = 1500;
            var sum = data[buildingId].Sum(result => result.Value.Data);
            Console.WriteLine(sum);

            // Aggregate data for all buildings with a given improvement.

            int improvementId = 5010;

            sum = data.Sum(improvements =>
            {
                Result result;
                return improvements.Value.TryGetValue(improvementId, out result) ? result.Data : 0.0;
            });

            Console.WriteLine(sum);
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

To speed up the second aggregation (for summing data for all improvements with a given ID) we can use a second dictionary:

```
//                      Improvment ID ↓               ↓ Building ID
var byImprovementId = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Result>>();
```

You would have an extra dictionary to maintain, but it's not too complicated. Having a few nested dictionaries like this might take too much memory though - but it's worth considering.

As noted in the comments below, it would be better to define types for the IDs and also for the dictionaries themselves. Putting that together gives:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    sealed class Result
    {
        public double Data;
    }

    sealed class BuildingId
    {
        public BuildingId(int id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }

        public readonly int Id;

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Id.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var other = obj as BuildingId;

            if (other == null)
                return false;

            return this.Id == other.Id;
        }
    }

    sealed class ImprovementId
    {
        public ImprovementId(int id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }

        public readonly int Id;

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Id.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var other = obj as ImprovementId;

            if (other == null)
                return false;

            return this.Id == other.Id;
        }
    }

    sealed class Building
    {
        public BuildingId Id;
        public int Value;
    }

    sealed class Improvement
    {
        public ImprovementId Id;
        public int Value;
    }

    sealed class BuildingResults : Dictionary<BuildingId, Result>{}

    sealed class ImprovementResults: Dictionary<ImprovementId, Result>{}

    sealed class BuildingsById: Dictionary<BuildingId, ImprovementResults>{}

    sealed class ImprovementsById: Dictionary<ImprovementId, BuildingResults>{}

    class Program
    {
        void run()
        {
            var byBuildingId    = CreateTestBuildingsById();            // Create some test data.
            var byImprovementId = CreateImprovementsById(byBuildingId); // Create the alternative lookup dictionaries.

            // Aggregate data for all improvements for building with ID == 1500:

            BuildingId buildingId = new BuildingId(1500);

            var sum = byBuildingId[buildingId].Sum(result => result.Value.Data);
            Console.WriteLine(sum);

            // Aggregate data for all buildings with a given improvement.

            ImprovementId improvementId = new ImprovementId(5010);

            sum = byBuildingId.Sum(improvements =>
            {
                Result result;
                return improvements.Value.TryGetValue(improvementId, out result) ? result.Data : 0.0;
            });

            Console.WriteLine(sum);

            // Aggregate data for all buildings with a given improvement using byImprovementId.
            // This will be much faster than the above Linq.

            sum = byImprovementId[improvementId].Sum(result => result.Value.Data);
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
        }

        static BuildingsById CreateTestBuildingsById()
        {
            var byBuildingId = new BuildingsById();

            for (int buildingKey = 1000; buildingKey < 2000; ++buildingKey)
            {
                var improvements = new ImprovementResults();

                for (int improvementKey = 5000; improvementKey < 5030; ++improvementKey)
                {
                    improvements.Add
                    (
                        new ImprovementId(improvementKey),
                        new Result
                        {
                            Data = buildingKey + improvementKey/1000.0
                        }
                    );
                }

                byBuildingId.Add(new BuildingId(buildingKey), improvements);
            }

            return byBuildingId;
        }

        static ImprovementsById CreateImprovementsById(BuildingsById byBuildingId)
        {
            var byImprovementId = new ImprovementsById();

            foreach (var improvements in byBuildingId)
            {
                foreach (var improvement in improvements.Value)
                {
                    if (!byImprovementId.ContainsKey(improvement.Key))
                        byImprovementId[improvement.Key] = new BuildingResults();

                    byImprovementId[improvement.Key].Add(improvements.Key, improvement.Value);
                }
            }

            return byImprovementId;
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here's a modified version which determines the time it takes to aggregate data for all instances of a building/improvement combination for a particular improvement and compares the results for dictionary of tuples with dictionary of dictionaries.

My results for a RELEASE build run outside any debugger:

```
Dictionary of dictionaries took 00:00:00.2967741
Dictionary of tuples took 00:00:07.8164672
```

It's significantly faster to use a dictionary of dictionaries, but this is only of importance if you intend to do many of these aggregations.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    sealed class Result
    {
        public double Data;
    }

    sealed class BuildingId
    {
        public BuildingId(int id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }

        public readonly int Id;

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Id.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var other = obj as BuildingId;

            if (other == null)
                return false;

            return this.Id == other.Id;
        }
    }

    sealed class ImprovementId
    {
        public ImprovementId(int id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }

        public readonly int Id;

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Id.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var other = obj as ImprovementId;

            if (other == null)
                return false;

            return this.Id == other.Id;
        }
    }

    sealed class Building
    {
        public BuildingId Id;
        public int Value;
    }

    sealed class Improvement
    {
        public ImprovementId Id;
        public int Value;
    }

    sealed class BuildingResults : Dictionary<BuildingId, Result>{}

    sealed class ImprovementResults: Dictionary<ImprovementId, Result>{}

    sealed class BuildingsById: Dictionary<BuildingId, ImprovementResults>{}

    sealed class ImprovementsById: Dictionary<ImprovementId, BuildingResults>{}

    class Program
    {
        void run()
        {
            var byBuildingId    = CreateTestBuildingsById();            // Create some test data.
            var byImprovementId = CreateImprovementsById(byBuildingId); // Create the alternative lookup dictionaries.
            var testTuples      = CreateTestTuples();

            ImprovementId improvementId = new ImprovementId(5010);

            int count = 10000;

            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                byImprovementId[improvementId].Sum(result => result.Value.Data);

            Console.WriteLine("Dictionary of dictionaries took " + sw.Elapsed);

            sw.Restart();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                testTuples.Where(result => result.Key.Item2.Equals(improvementId)).Sum(item => item.Value.Data);

            Console.WriteLine("Dictionary of tuples took " + sw.Elapsed);
        }

        static Dictionary<Tuple<BuildingId, ImprovementId>, Result> CreateTestTuples()
        {
            var result = new Dictionary<Tuple<BuildingId, ImprovementId>, Result>();

            for (int buildingKey = 1000; buildingKey < 2000; ++buildingKey)
                for (int improvementKey = 5000; improvementKey < 5030; ++improvementKey)
                    result.Add(
                        new Tuple<BuildingId, ImprovementId>(new BuildingId(buildingKey), new ImprovementId(improvementKey)),
                        new Result
                        {
                            Data = buildingKey + improvementKey/1000.0
                        });

            return result;
        }

        static BuildingsById CreateTestBuildingsById()
        {
            var byBuildingId = new BuildingsById();

            for (int buildingKey = 1000; buildingKey < 2000; ++buildingKey)
            {
                var improvements = new ImprovementResults();

                for (int improvementKey = 5000; improvementKey < 5030; ++improvementKey)
                {
                    improvements.Add
                    (
                        new ImprovementId(improvementKey),
                        new Result
                        {
                            Data = buildingKey + improvementKey/1000.0
                        }
                    );
                }

                byBuildingId.Add(new BuildingId(buildingKey), improvements);
            }

            return byBuildingId;
        }

        static ImprovementsById CreateImprovementsById(BuildingsById byBuildingId)
        {
            var byImprovementId = new ImprovementsById();

            foreach (var improvements in byBuildingId)
            {
                foreach (var improvement in improvements.Value)
                {
                    if (!byImprovementId.ContainsKey(improvement.Key))
                        byImprovementId[improvement.Key] = new BuildingResults();

                    byImprovementId[improvement.Key].Add(improvements.Key, improvement.Value);
                }
            }

            return byImprovementId;
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use a dictionary of dictionaries, you might want to create some classes to make it obvious what the keys mean - int is not a very informative description. So you might want to define Dictionary<BindingId, Dictionary<ImprovementId, Result>> where BindingId and ImprovementId are classes which wrap int values

Comment: @Aidan Yes, I agree - this is just a suggestion of an overall approach not a complete solution.

Comment: " You could use a "dictionary of dictionaries" ... This would let you quickly find the improvements for a particular building". Eh, the Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, ...> will be actually faster (one lookup in dictionary). Your solution only helps when he would need to search by both Improvements and Buildings, but if it would be only occasionally, he could use something like dict.Where(result => result.Key.Item2.Equals(...)) which is close to O(n) time complexity and therefore not worth the increased code complexity of 2xNxM dicts.

Comment: @eMko Aye, that's probably right. Guess you'd have to do some timings, but I agree the dictionaries seem too complicated.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I need to solve this kind of problems on daily basis in my work, so I have a cheatsheet with .Net collections and their time complexities for particular operations sticked to a wall near my monitor :-) . Your code is definetely worth using when you need "random" access for a few Results in a way Building->Improvement and Improvement->Building very often. It's like indexes in SQL table (or if you used SortedDictionary, then exactly that, 'cause it uses a B-Tree). But does not help for Sum and Avg much. And it slows adding a new Result quite a lot (even if you do it parallel)

Comment: @eMko Well I just did some timing test code, and it seems that doing a linear search through a dictionary of tuples takes more than 20 times as long to calculate the sum. I'll attach test code.